# Parsing HTML page to extract links

Tags: c#, regex

I want to parse html file and extract links from `<a>` tag. For example I am trying to extract link from following `<a>` tag.

> `<a class="thumb vtop inlblk rel tdnone linkWithHash scale5 detailsLink" href="http://olx.com.pk/item/honda-civic-exi-2005-IDSkzkt.html#6256e9ac30" title="">                         <img class="fleft" src="http://img03.olx.com.pk/images_olxpk/89491775_1_144x108_honda-civic-exi-2005-lahore_rev001.jpg" alt="Honda Civic Exi 2005"> </a>`

I use the following regular expression

```
private const string _LINK_REGEX = "href=\"[a-zA-Z./:&\\d_-]+\"";
```

But I am unable to extract this url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
href=\"[^\"]+\"
```

Test [here](http://regex101.com/r/bW2pL8/1)